# C# Serialport not receiving all the bytes in a single transmission

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm using the following code to receive hex data over the serial port, it seems that some of these transmissions are broken up into 2 lines when they are parts of the same transmission. How do I make sure that each transmission is received properly?

```
public void Receiver(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string data;

    do
    {
        data = COMPort.ReadExisting();
    } while (COMPort.BytesToRead != 0);

    RxARR = data.ToCharArray().ToList();
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(Display)); // Start "Display" on the UI thread
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You should never assume that data from a serial port is provided to you in one go (the same is true for network communication by the way). You need to make sure that your code accepts a message only if you have received everything.

*Everything* is hard to define. This can either be all characters until a defined termination sequence (for example `\r\n` or `EOL` byte) or until a fixed number of bytes is read. Generally one can say, as *every* message can be fragmented, reliable communcation is not possible without a defined *end of message* signal.

What we do is:

1. Create a `StringBuilder`
2. Read everything into that `StringBuilder`
3. Search for termination sequence
4. Remove everything from the `StringBuilder` up to and including the termination sequence
5. Process that chunk of data
6. Repeat from 3 until termination sequence is not found
7. **Keep the remaining characters** in `StringBuilder`, as this is the start of a new message

Pseudo code:

```
private StringBuilder serialBuffer = new StringBuilder();
private string terminationSequence = "\r\n"; // Anything that can't be part of a message

public void Receiver(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string data = COMPort.ReadExisting();
    serialBuffer.Append(data);

    string bufferString = serialBuffer.ToString();

    int index = -1;
    do
    {
        index = bufferString.IndexOf(terminationSequence);  
        if (index > -1)
        {
            string message = bufferString.Substring(0, index);
            bufferString = bufferString.Remove(0, index + terminationSequence.Length);

            HandleMessage(message);
        }
    }
    while (index > -1)

    serialBuffer = new StringBuilder(bufferString);
}
```

---

By the way: Looping within your `DataReceived` event is not desired, as this event is called by the `SerialPort` whenever something new is ready to be read. Reading in a loop may interfere with what `SerialPort` is doing by default. So: Don't read in a loop within that event! The "loop" is the event being fired in sequence by `SerialPort`.

Comment: what is the equivalent of terminationSequence in vb.net?

Comment: what did you mean by terminationSequence?

Comment: I mean a defined sequence of bytes that is not part of any messages and as such allows you to determine whether a message is complete. When you encounter that (sequence of) byte, the message is over.

Comment: @adib In the code above, the termination sequence is just a string. I'm going to change my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: if possible could you please answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868157/how-to-read-data-from-serial-port-in-vb-net

Comment: If you shouldn't do this in the DataRecieved event, how should you structure it? Call a function from the DataRecieved event?

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't process anything in DataReceived, but you shouldn't mix DataReceived and looping/waiting. DataReceived will be called whenever there's something to be received. So what I do: I have a buffer for serial input. I fill this buffer in DataReceived with what's there, and if the buffer contains a complete message (or more) I handle that message, after removing it from the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I Had almost the same situation.

Like Thorsten said the data sometimes does not come at once..
Maybe because of Hardware or BaundRate..

What really works for me was:

```
        var end = '\r';
        int dataLength = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
        int nbrDataRead = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);

        RxString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
        txtCod.AppendText(RxString);

        if (RxString.IndexOf((char)end) > -1)
        {
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(Final));   
        }
```

Comment: what will be the equivalent of this in vb.net?

Comment: Not Tested Yet, But i believe smth like this. 
`Dim [end] = ControlChars.Cr
Dim dataLength As Integer = _serialPort.BytesToRead
Dim data As Byte() = New Byte(dataLength - 1) {}
Dim nbrDataRead As Integer = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength)

RxString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data)
txtCod.AppendText(RxString)

If RxString.IndexOf(CChar([end])) > -1 Then
 Me.Invoke(New EventHandler(Final))
End If`

Comment: can you please help me to convert only this part to dotnet?  if (RxString.IndexOf((char)end) > -1)
        {
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(Final));   
        }

Comment: @Adib Something like this , `If RxString.IndexOf(CChar([end])) > -1 Then
 Me.Invoke(New EventHandler(Final))
End If`